# Se sobreescriben los valores de una lista en Python-Maple

Tags: python

Soy principiante en la programación. El origen del trabajo es modificar un código de maple con la sintaxis de python. Agrego 2 valores, uno para n y otro para r, como resultado me debe generar un conjunto de números. r determinará la cantidad de números entre los [] y n la cantidad de estos conjuntos.
Por ejemplo, si asigno (r,n)=(2,3), debe obtenerse: [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3].
Después de un rato me enfrento con este problema en python.
"ai` va tomando los valores que quiero pero al almacenarlos en la variable índices, todas sus entradas toman el mismo valor que el de su última entrada"

Obtengo esto como resultado, suponiendo los valores para r,n como (3,4):

```
1
[list([1, 2, 3, 4])]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Cuando debería obtener algo así:

```
[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]
```

**Este es el fragmento de código en Maple2019**

```
 restart:
 with(LinearAlgebra):
 with(plots):
 with(plottools):
 # ---------------------------------------------- #
 # -Obtiene el arreglo de r - tuplas (índices) en #
 # -un espacio de dimensión n, para un r fijo---- #
 # ---------------------------------------------- #
 rInd := proc(r, n)
 local ai, j, i, Indices, k, aux: 

 # - Inicialización de las variables - #
ai := [seq(i, i = 1 .. r)]: # ------------------ # r - tuplas
j := r: # -------------------------------------- # Posición a examinar
Indices := NULL: # ----------------------------- # Arreglo de Índices
Indices := Indices, ai:

while ai[1] < (n - r + 1) do 
  if ai[j] < (n - r + j) then
     if j = r then
        ai[j] := ai[j] + 1:
        Indices := Indices, ai:
     end:

     if j < r then
        aux := ai[j]:
        for k from 1 to r - j + 1 by 1 do
           ai[j + k - 1] := aux + k:
        end:
        Indices := Indices, ai:
        j := r:
     end:
  else
     j := j - 1:
  end:
    end:

 return Indices:
 end:
 rInd(2, 3);
```

**Este es el fragmento de código de python**

```
 import numpy  
 import numpy as np  
 from numpy import random



 def binomial(n, r): 
     p = 1 
     for i in range(1, min(r, n - r) + 1): 
         p *= n 
         p //= i 
         n -= 1 
     return p 

 n = int(input("Agregar valor de n: ")) 
 r = int(input("Agregar valor de r: ")) 

 print(binomial(n, r)) 

 ai = list(range(1, r + 1)) 
 j = r 
 Indices = np.array([None]*binomial(n,r)) 

 cont = 0 
 Indices[cont]=(ai) 
 print(Indices) 
 cont=cont+1 

 while ai[0] < (n - r + 1): 
    if ai[j - 1] < (n - r + j): 
        if j == r: 
            ai[j - 1] = ai[j - 1] + 1 
            print(ai) 
             Indices[cont] = (ai) 
             cont = cont + 1 
             print(Indices) 
         elif j < r: 
             aux = ai[j - 1] 
             for k in range(1, r - j + 2): 
                ai[j + k - 2] = aux + k 
             Indices[cont] = (ai) 
             cont = cont + 1 
            j = r 
     else: 
         j = j - 1 

print(Indices) 
print(ai)
```

Comment: Bienvenido Elias, te recomiendo que reformules el problema porque no se entiende como se conforma lo esperado frente a lo que te sucede. Te invito a leer [¿como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta tenga una mejor aceptación

Comment: gracias, lo cambiaré